# Updating a column from values

Tags: sql, greenplum

I want to update a column col_123 in table TT from values such that some criteria are met.

The following is a piece of my code, where I have two values. But in my actual code, there are thousands of value rows.

```
    UPDATE TT
    SET col_123 = T2.score
    FROM 
        (values ('1007163',2016,3,80.09), ('1034758',2013,4,68.85)) T2(person_id_t2, id_yr_t2, id_qtr_t2, score)
    WHERE person_id = T2.person_id_t2 AND id_yr = T2.id_yr_t2 AND id_qtr = T2.id_qtr_t2;
```

But even with these two rows, it takes forever to update the table. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the output with EXPLAIN ANALYZE:

```
Update (slice0; segments: 56)  (rows=1 width=3903)
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=0.06..750889.50 rows=1 width=3903)
        Hash Cond: TT.person_id::text = "*VALUES*".column1 AND TT.id_yr = "*VALUES*".column2::numeric AND TT.id_qtr = "*VALUES*".column3
        Rows out:  Avg 1.0 rows x 2 workers.  Max 1 rows (seg29) with 236406 ms to first row, 236407 ms to end, start offset by 370 ms.
        Executor memory:  1K bytes avg, 1K bytes max (seg0).
        Work_mem used:  1K bytes avg, 1K bytes max (seg0). Workfile: (0 spilling, 0 reused)
        (seg29)  Hash chain length 1.0 avg, 1 max, using 2 of 262151 buckets.
        ->  Seq Scan on seamless_health_index  (cost=0.00..466843.92 rows=676299 width=3871)
              Rows out:  Avg 676405.3 rows x 56 workers.  Max 678281 rows (seg27) with 0.524 ms to first row, 243299 ms to end, start offset by 369 ms.
        ->  Hash  (cost=0.03..0.03 rows=1 width=72)
              Rows in:  Avg 2.0 rows x 56 workers.  Max 2 rows (seg0) with 0.080 ms to end, start offset by 375 ms.
              ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..0.03 rows=1 width=72)
                    Rows out:  Avg 2.0 rows x 56 workers.  Max 2 rows (seg0) with 0.017 ms to first row, 0.020 ms to end, start offset by 375 ms.
Slice statistics:
  (slice0)    Executor memory: 5769K bytes avg x 56 workers, 5769K bytes max (seg0).  Work_mem: 1K bytes max.
Statement statistics:
  Memory used: 128000K bytes
Settings:  from_collapse_limit=16; join_collapse_limit=16
Total runtime: 308388.391 ms
```

Thanks!

Note: The table TT has about 40,000,000 rows, and 1000 columns, but only two of the rows and col_123 should be updated.

Comment: Please edit the question and add `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the query.

Comment: Maybe it's waiting for a lock: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, thanks! I just updated the question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, there shouldn't be a lock as I have just created the table TT myself, and no one else can use it.

Comment: That is not an execution plan from a normal Postgres server. What does `select version()` show you?

Comment: It's actually Green Plum: PostgreSQL 8.2.15 (Greenplum Database 4.3.4.1 build 2) on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 4.4.2 compiled on Feb 10 2015 14:15:10

Comment: Does the "EXPLAIN ANALYZE" help at all? Is there is a way to fix this? I appreciate any help.

Comment: Is TT partitioned?  Can you eliminate partitions?  Can you put the values of T2 into a table instead of this odd virtual table with hard coded values?  Where did the data from T2 come from?  You have thousands?  You clearly aren't manually typing this in.

Comment: Materialize t2.  t2 should be distributed by the same key as tt for best performance.  If you need to create a table for t2, make it appendonly.  Run vacuum on tt because it could be bloated from updates.  Eliminate partitions if possible on tt so it doesn't have to scan all partitions.

Comment: @jonRoberts, Thanks! How can I run vacuum and eliminate partitions? Yes TT is distributed, and I can upload T2 (my assumption was that it won't make a difference, but I can certainly do that.)

Comment: TT needs to be partitioned in order to eliminate partitions.

Comment: I created a table for T2 and it's distributed the same way (which was a hassle by the way, since now I'm pushing data in chunks of 1000 rows, to be on the safe side). I guess that has helped a little, but the join is still really slow (although it's better than before). Except, I have added the overhead of creating a new table and inserting to that table.

Answer (score -1):

Create an index on `TT (person_id::text, id_yr, id_qtr)`.

Then a nested loop join can be used, which should find the one matching row faster.

You don't have to include *all* three columns in the index, only those where the join condition is selective.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this a little more? For example, I don't know how to perform a nested loop join, and I also don't know how to create the index that you are suggesting. (My SQL knowledge is terribly rusty.)

Comment: @JonRoberts, logically a lighter indexing should improve the performance, I think it can be used along with your suggestions? Am I wrong?

Comment: For PostgreSQL, an index would help but for Greenplum, you typically don't use an index.  You first look at the distribution key, then partitioning/storage options.